# expected params to be a map error when trying to submit form in Phoenix 1.3

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a contact form, using the below changeset.

```
def changeset(%Email{} = email, attrs) do

    email
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :email, :message, :event])
    |> validate_required([:name, :email, :message])
  end
```

But I get the following error when I try to submit the form:

```
expected params to be a map, got: `#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %
{email: "cooper.sf@gmail.com", event: "wedding", message: "hello", name: "Simon"}, 
errors: [], data: #Iotc.Contact.Email<>, valid?: true>`
```

my create function is:

```
  def create(conn, %{"email" => email_params}) do
    changeset = Contact.Email.changeset(%Iotc.Contact.Email{}, email_params)
    case Contact.create_email(changeset) do
      {:ok, email} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Email sent")
        |> redirect(to: email_path(conn, :index))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:error, "Something went wrong")
        |> render("index.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

I'm assuming it's not picking up the `attrs`?

And from contact.ex:

```
  def create_email(attrs \\ %{}) do
    %Email{}
    |> Email.changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.insert()
  end
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of `Contact.create_email`? Does it accept a changeset or just attrs? I think you want to do `Contact.create_email(email_params)`.

Comment: @Dogbert just added to OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Contact.create_email/1` expects a map of attrs (not a changeset) and calls `Contact.Email.changeset/2` itself, so you need to pass `email_params` to it:

```
def create(conn, %{"email" => email_params}) do
  case Contact.create_email(email_params) do
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: That's fixed it and I can see a new record in the db.  Thanks @dogbert